# Making sense of rocket engine thrust calculation

Tags: engine-design, thrust, calculation

Recently I've been trying to design a hypothetical rocket engine using the mass flow rate, exit mach, temperature, and pressure calculations provided by NASA's own website. I've come to know quite most of the operating principles of a rocket engine, but have absolutely no idea how the heck these calculations are used.

In my case, the throat diameter is 1.6 cm, the expansion ratio 21.4, and the chamber pressure 20 bar, and so it'd be very helpful if any examples used referenced these parameters. I would very much appreciate an intuitive explanation as many of the explanations I've found have been too brief and difficult to understand(and rightly so).

https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/rktthsum.html

Comment: Are you asking for an explanation of the equations on that link (i.e. their derivations) or how to use them? Specifics on what you don't understand would improve this question a lot.